# HttpError 500 when running the quickstart,py from Google Drive API samples

Tags: google-drive-api

I have started exploring Google Drive API and was trying the sample python code given in API reference page. It was running alright the first time I ran it. Lately it has been giving the following error

**googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=10&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%29&alt=json returned "Internal Error">**

Below is the link to the code I used
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python

Comment: Did you change anything? Can you try creating a new clientID with a new client_secret.json (basically start all over again) and run it in a virtual environment if it changes anything? Mine is working pretty fine right now.

Comment: I did not change anything. I just tried after a few minutes and it is working again. Weird! Is there a limit to number of requests I can make?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were affected by the brief [service disruption in Google servers](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=768deb9fad2a675680dbee7e8712bc41). But this is fixed now so try again.
Error 500 means it's the server's fault.